Why do I have to pass data through param in Laravel?
I'm developing a laravel api using resource controller. There I have to use PUT method for updating something.
When I try to pass data through body with form-data the validation error happens. I have to pass the data through param.
Is this normal for laravel resource controller? If so why?
Here's my code.
public function update(RoleRequest $request, string $id)
{
     $data = Role::find($id);

     $new_data = [
         'name' => $request->name
     ];

     $data->update($new_data);

     return $this->apiResponse(true, 'role updated successfully', $data, 200);
}

Here's the validation error.
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Validation errors",
    "data": {
        "name": [
            "The name field is required."
        ]
    }
}


Please, do not upload images of code or errors.

@LucaPuddu Why? Any reason for this.

Try to read the link in my comment.

Thanks. I'll replace with actual code instead

So, the error is straight forward, you are not sending the data... I do not understand what you do not understand about the error

I know the error and I know the solution. In this case, if I pass the data through param, everything is fine. But when I pass the data through form-data (body), the validation error happens.
The thing I want to know is why do I need to pass data through param. Why can't I pass through body? In the above error json,I passed data through body.

@tuna_tumi See here. It's a known issue with PHP, not even Laravel.
You need to actually use POST as a method when you send the request, and add _method=PUT as a param (or in the form data!)

@tuna_tumi "But when I pass the data through form-data (body), the validation error happens" because you must have validation rules defined. Have a look in your RoleRequest code for something like 'name' => 'required'. URL parameters are not validated in the same way as data in the request body.

@Tony Yes, I defined validation rules for this function. The concern is now clear. It's as Luca said in the above comment.

I don't think Laravel still has the problem described in the answer Lua linked to - that was six years ago. I use POST, PATCH, and PUT in Laravel without an issue. When you send data in the body and have validation rules defined in the request object, those validation rules are applied. If you wrote the validation to require the name why are you surprised the validation fails if you don't supply that attribute? If you want different validation rules for PUT or PATCH, use a different Request class.

@Tony it will be fixed in PHP 8.4. See the last message of the PHP bug report

@Luca I've not read the entire thread, but my understanding of that bug is it's only an issue when using multipart/form-data requests. In this case I assume they are using application/json which I've not had any issues with in Laravel.

@Tony that's possible, I haven't tested with application/json. Don't we sometimes need multipart/form-data if we're uploading a file? (which seems not to be the case here anyway)

the error message is clear, by using RoleRequest, you are validating the parameters entered in the request before it reaches the rest of the function. This is very useful to ensure that the fields that are required arrive.
You can go into RoleRequest and see that you have the field name as required. That means that the failure is due to not having sent that parameter in the request of your call.

I've copied my comment to this answer so I can add more information.
I don't think Laravel still has the problem described in the answer Lua linked to - that was six years ago. I use POST, PATCH, and PUT in Laravel without an issue.
When you send data in the body and have validation rules defined in the request object, those validation rules are applied. If you wrote the validation to require the name why are you surprised the validation fails if you don't supply that attribute? If you want different validation rules for PUT or PATCH, use a different Request class.
However, I don't think you should be using PUT to update your resource. The semantic of a PUT action is to replace the resource with the data provided.
If the validation of a POST request is to require the name attribute, why would you not require it if you are replacing the resource?
Use PATCH when you only want a partial update and write a new RoleUpdateRequest class to validate fields only when they are present.
